# MySQL returns all rows when field=0 from SECOND Select query

Tags: mysql, select

This case is similar to: S.O Question; [mySQL returns all rows when field=0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880936/mysql-returns-all-rows-when-field-0), and the Accepted answer was a very simple trick, to souround the ZERO with single quotes

FROM:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE email=0
```

TO:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE email='0'
```

However, my case is slightly different in that my Query is something like:

```
   SELECT * FROM table WHERE email=( 
         SELECT my_column_value FROM myTable WHERE my_column_value=0 AND user_id =15 LIMIT 1 )
```

Which in a sense, becomes like simply saying: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE email=0`, but now with a `Second Query`.

**PLEASE NOTE:** It is a *MUST* that I use the `SECOND QUERY`.

When I tried:  `SELECT * FROM table WHERE email='( SELECT my_column_value FROM myTable WHERE my_column_value=0 LIMIT 1 )'` ***(Notice the Single Quotes on the second query)***

`MySql` *SCREAMED* `Errors near '(.`

How can this be achieved

Any Suggestion is highly honored

---

**EDIT1: For a visual perspective of the Query**

See the STEN_TB here: http://snag.gy/Rq8dq.jpg

Now, the main aim is to get the `sten_h` where `rawscore_h` = 0;

The **CURRENT QUERY** as a whole.

```
SELECT sten_h
                FROM sten_tb
                WHERE rawscore_h =  (
                SELECT `for_print_stens_rowscore`
                FROM `for_print_stens_tb`
                WHERE `for_print_stens_student_id` =3
                AND `for_print_stens_factor_name` = 'Factor H' )
```

The result of the `Second Query`  can be any number including **ZERO**.

Any number from `>=1` Works and returns a single *corresponding* value from `sten_h`. Only `=0` does not Work, it returns all rows

That's the issue.

### **CORRECT ANSWER OR SOLUTION FOR THIS**

Just in case someone ends up in this paradox, the ***Accepted*** answer has it all.

SEE `STEN_TB`:  http://snag.gy/Rq8dq.jpg

SEE The desired `Query` result here: http://snag.gy/wa4yA.jpg

Comment: Tried `IN` Still returns all rows

Comment: You need the quotes only around the value: WHERE my_column_value='0'

Comment: @DariusX. That's what I said in the Question... Now the problem, **how to deal with the zero when it is the result of a Second Query??**

Comment: @UniversalGrasp, try  select cast(my_column as varchar(1)) from mytable

Comment: I get ERROR: **#1064** -*You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'varchar(1)) FROM `for_print_stens_tb` WHERE `for_print_stens_student_id`' at line 4`*

Comment: Show your table definition and error message.

Comment: @philipxy Please See EDIT1, It has an image of the actual table. Thank you again

Comment: That is not a table definition. If your table is generated by code in another language give that code. Also avoid links when you can put things inline. Although that that enormous illustration is not useful here. Also it is clipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your issue is with implicit datatype conversions. You can make those datatype conversions explicit, to gain control.

(The "trick" with wrapping a literal 0 in single quotes, that makes the literal a string literal, rather than a numeric.)

In the more general case, you can use a `CAST` or `CONVERT` function to explicitly specify a datatype conversion. You can use an expression in place of a column name, wherever you need to...

For example, to get the value returned by `my_column_value` to match the datatype of the `email` column, assuming `email` is character type, something like:

```
... email = (SELECT CONVERT(my_column_value,CHAR(255)) FROM myTable WHERE ...
```

or, to get the a literal integer value to be a string value:

```
 ... FROM myTable WHERE my_column_value = CONVERT(0,CHAR(30)) ...
```

Comment: SUPERB!!.... It worked when I tried the `(CONVERT(...,...))` trick. Thanking you again. (Accepted)

Answer (score 0):

If email and my_column_value are just indicating true or false then they should almost certainly be both BIT NOT NULL or other two-value type that your schema uses for booleans. (Your ORM may use a particular one.) Casting is frequently a hack made necessary by a poor design.

If it should be a particular user then you shouldn't use LIMIT because tables are unordered and that doesn't return a particular user. Explain in your question what your query is supposed to return including exactly what you mean by "15th".

(Having all those similar columns is bad design: rawscore_a, sten_a, rawscore_b, sten_b,... . Use a table with two columns: rawscore, sten.)