# MySQL Returns All Rows When field = 0

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

I've seen a few questions on here very similar to this however I have not found an answer specific to what I believe my problem to be.

I have two tables, `subcompanies` and `presets`. The two tables are linked together through an ID, `CntRefID` and `PresetIDFoxPro`. I want to select all of the text from the `Preset` table's text column when the ID's matchup.

This works flawlessly when the `CntRefID` has a number in it. However, if it is 0 then every single field from the `presets` text column is returned instead.

This is my query text;

```
myQuery.CommandText =   
"SELECT CompanyID, CompanyName, PresetText, InvHeader, Prefix, NextBnum  
FROM sdcdatabase.sdcsubcompanies, sdcdatabase.presets   
WHERE (CntRef=PresetIDFoxPro OR CntRef='0') AND PresetReferenceFoxPro=3";
```

I cannot get my head round why every field is selected. I have tried 0 in quotes and without quotes, I have also seen it could be due to one field being an Integer and one being a Char ([mySQL returns all rows when field=0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880936/mysql-returns-all-rows-when-field-0)). Both my fields are integers however.

Comment: Why does your query include the `OR CntRef='0'` condition? Is it because you know there are no matching `presets` records with that ID, and you want to return `subcompanies` records even when they don't have a match on `presets` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All rows from the `presets` table are returned due to the `OR CntRef='0'` condition (where `CntRef` is 0).

This is because your existing `where` clause can be paraphrased (ignoring the `PresetReferenceFoxPro` condition) as:

> I want all records from the `subcompanies` table and either any matching records from the `presets` table, or all records from the `presets` table where `CntRef` is 0 on the `subcompanies` table.

If you want to return `subcompanies` records even when they don't have a match on presets, then you need to use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` - like so:

```
SELECT CompanyID, CompanyName, PresetText, InvHeader, Prefix, NextBnum 
FROM sdcdatabase.sdcsubcompanies as s 
LEFT OUTER JOIN sdcdatabase.presets as p 
ON s.CntRef=p.PresetIDFoxPro AND p.PresetReferenceFoxPro=3
```

I'm assuming that `PresetReferenceFoxPro` is on the `presets` table - it would clarify the query to add table aliases to each of the columns in the `SELECT` clause, but I don't know which columns come from which tables.

Comment: Working fine thanks, just to add if I had a third table that I did not want to involve in the join, where would it fit in?

Comment: @CBreeze - it would depend on what you want to do with it - I suggest opening a new question, with the relevant details of which fields are on which tables included.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your "where" by removing "or" or add more conditions

```
 WHERE (CntRef=PresetIDFoxPro) .... other conditions
```

Just for example

Comment: Isn't the 'AND PresetIDFoxPro<>0' superfluous - if PresetIDFoxPro were equal to zero then the left side of the expression would be true making the entire expression true.