# Where field=0 returns all records

Tags: mysql

I am using Mysql, I have a field which type is `varchar(50)` and name is `email` and if I execute a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM  `users` WHERE email =0
```

It returns all records on the table. How can is this possible?

**Example:**

Records one of them: `gorkemasan24@gmail.com` and this query returns this row too.

Why is this happening and how to avoid this situtation?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this test. If you want to filter `NULL`s, you need to write `IS NULL`...

Comment: No, I saw this query on slow queries list.

Comment: if you email is varchar you should compare it with quotes like `email = '0'` or `email = ''` ...comparing it to a number is wrong it's probably trying to convert all your emails into numbers and comparing it with zero which any string returns a 1 which is true

Comment: You should have a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880936/mysql-returns-all-rows-when-field-0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you compare a string field to a number, it converts the string to a number, and then compares those numbers. Converting a string to a number uses the number at the beginning of the string; if it doesn't begin with a number, it converts to `0`.

So if you had an email like `12james@domain.com` it wouldn't be returned, because that converts to `12`. But `gorkemasan24@gmail.com` converts to `0`.

You should write `WHERE email = '0'` to compare it to a string rather than a number. Or if you want to test for an empty email, use `WHERE email = ''`.