# MySQL returns a result for a WHERE clause that shouldn't match

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, where one has a reference to the other table. For testing purposes, I created these two tables

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test1`;
CREATE TABLE `test1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `test2_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `test1_test2_id_fk` (`test2_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `test1_test2_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`test2_id`) REFERENCES `test2` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


LOCK TABLES `test1` WRITE;
INSERT INTO `test1` VALUES (1,1);
UNLOCK TABLES;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test2`;
CREATE TABLE `test2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

LOCK TABLES `test2` WRITE;
INSERT INTO `test2` VALUES (1,'group','Baustahl');
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

So far so good, but when I now execute this query:

`SELECT * FROM test1 t1 JOIN test2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.test2_id WHERE t2.name = 'group' AND t2.value = 0;`

IMO it should yield an empty result, because the `value` in my db is `Baustahl` and I'm querying for `0`. However, the `Baustahl` result is returned as you can see here

[image: screenshot of db result]

I can't seem to find the reason for this behavior as it is def. not my expectation. Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: what is you expectation  ?.. add  the expetced  result

Comment: ... I did ... Quote: "IMO it should yield an empty result, because the value in my db is Baustahl and I'm querying for 0" .... maybe read the post first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your t2.value is varchar you should use  '0'

```
SELECT * 
FROM test1 t1 
JOIN test2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.test2_id WHERE t2.name = 'group' AND t2.value = '0';
```

the nuemric  0 value is not converted  as you think

Comment: Thank you. Just found this post here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7881095/2823419 which describes the same problem. Apparently it is because MySQL converts the field to an `integer`, invalid `integer` means `0`, that's why it finds results. IMO not a good behavior by MySQL. I'll accept this answer as soon as I'm able to.